# How to get a longer provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I made a free developer account on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). Then I opened account tab in Xcode 8 settings, added my account and created the iOS development signing identity. From that moment Xcode creates provisioning profiles for me so I can run my applications made in Xcode on my iPhone.

The problem is that provisioning profiles last only for one week and I have to resign my app every week to run it on my device.

How to get more durable provisioning profile? Or how to make apps from the Xcode work on one specified iOS device for a longer time? If impossible without paying, how long provisioning profile is it possible to get with payed account?

Comment: by using a paid apple dev account heh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade to a paid developer account.  With a paid account, you can create a certificate that will have a 3 year expiration, and provisioning profile that will have a 1 year expiration date.  So basically it will get you a build that will last for up to a year ("up to" because unless you create the provisioning profile on the day you do the build, it will be less than 1 year).